# Nagios Invalid Password

Tags: nagios, nagiosxi

First I get this error `"connect to address 10.0.0.102 and port 12489: Connection refused"`, then I made some changes according to forums and I changed `nclient.ini` file. I adjusted the allowed hosts and password.
Then server side the *Status Information* is changed. Now I get this error in Nagios Admin Panel:

```
NSClient - ERROR: Invalid password.
```

However, at Nagios XI Server I checked password and it's same as in `nsclient.ini` file on client side.

I used this command to check:

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nt -H 'hostname' -s nagpasswd -p 12489 -v CPULOAD -w 80 -c 90 -l 5,80,90,10,80,9 NSClient
```

What might be the issue? Any help would be perfect.

Comment: What about NSClient logs on client side? Is there any relevant information about this error?

Answer (score 0):

after changing the password , you need to restart your nagios service once